# How to fix this common mistake in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, closures

I am studying closures in Javascript on 
[mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). There is a section called common mistake which totally blew me away. I don't know what it's really talking about.

the code is as follow,

```
<p id="help">Helpful notes will appear here</p>
<p>E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"></p>
<p>Age: <input type="text" id="age" name="age"></p>
function showHelp(help) {
  document.getElementById('help').innerHTML = help;
}

function setupHelp() {
  var helpText = [
      {'id': 'email', 'help': 'Your e-mail address'},
      {'id': 'name', 'help': 'Your full name'},
      {'id': 'age', 'help': 'Your age (you must be over 16)'}
    ];

  for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
    var item = helpText[i];
    document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function() {
      showHelp(item.help);
    }
  }
}

setupHelp();
```

The text appear in help

will only show the last help "Your age (you must be over 16)"
 and the solution is to rewrite the showHelp function outside setupHelp

```
function makeHelpCallback(help) {
  return function() {
    showHelp(help);
  };
}

function setupHelp() {
  var helpText = [
      {'id': 'email', 'help': 'Your e-mail address'},
      {'id': 'name', 'help': 'Your full name'},
      {'id': 'age', 'help': 'Your age (you must be over 16)'}
    ];

  for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
    var item = helpText[i];
    document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = makeHelpCallback(item.help);
  }
}

setupHelp();
```

I don't understand the mechanism why it fixes the problem. Since I never use javascript to access DOM, but jQuery, I rewrote the function in jQuery

```
function makeHelpCallback(i) {
    return function () {
        $("#help").text(i);
    };
}
(function () {
    var helpText = [
    { 'id': 'email', 'help': 'Your e-mail address' },
    { 'id': 'name', 'help': 'Your full name' },
    { 'id': 'age', 'help': 'Your age (you must be over 16)' }
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
        var item = helpText[i];
        $("#"+item.id).focus(function () {
            new makeHelpCallback(item.help)();
        });
    }
})();
```

But the bug doesn't go away. As far as I know, jQuery doesn't have onfocus handler, it's impossible to bind the handler to its listener on the same level. It has to go under function(){}. And I cannot achieve the same effect as Javascript can do.

So is there anyway to write the code equivalent to the Javascript code?

As the explanation says it doesn't work because the listeners share the same environment. Whatever it means, onfocus = function(){showHelp(item.help)} executed three separate times. They should be bound accordingly. Why they would come up the same? Because showHelp is a static object? If so, adding a new modifier should do the work. And makeHelpCallback(item.help) share the same environment too. But it works.
Why Why Why???

for your testing convenience, full HTML code is attached.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="help">Helpful notes will appear here</p>
    <p>E-mail:
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>
    <p>Name:
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"></p>
    <p>Age:
        <input type="text" id="age" name="age"></p>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function makeHelpCallback(i) {
            return function () {
                $("#help").text(i);
            };
        }
        (function () {
            var helpText = [
            { 'id': 'email', 'help': 'Your e-mail address' },
            { 'id': 'name', 'help': 'Your full name' },
            { 'id': 'age', 'help': 'Your age (you must be over 16)' }
            ];

            for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
                var item = helpText[i];
                $("#" + item.id).focus(function () {
                    makeHelpCallback(item.help)();
                });
            }
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a more simplified example of the same mistake: http://jsfiddle.net/5Anca/

Comment: The linked Mozilla page provides a perfectly adequate explanation. Suggest you read it through a few more times.

Comment: sorry, English is my second or third language.
i have done my best

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you the answer below but I suggest you try to figure it out for yourself. some hints :

What exactly are you passing to the `focus` method?

How are your function's variables defined? Remember, you need to understand *when* your function is executed.

In your code :

```
$("#"+item.id).focus(function () {
        new makeHelpCallback(item.help)();
    });
```

passed a *function* to `focus`, this function is invoked later (when the focus event occurs), after the loop is finished and the `item` variable is set to the last item. What you should do, is pass a function with its own local variable that is bound as you call `focus`. This was the whole point of the `makeHelpCallback`! Your code should be like this :

```
 $("#"+item.id).focus(makeHelpCallback(item.help));
```

`makeHelpCallback` returns a function, here, write it all inline if that's clearer for you :

```
$("#"+item.id).focus((function (i) {
    // this function is executed immediately
    // i is bound to the correct item.
    return function () {
        $("#help").text(i);
    };
})());
```

Comment: Thx a lot! I never know what focus(function()) do. 
now i do!

Comment: hah, that would make this example more difficult to understand! I'm glad you figured it out, I think Joe's example is a lot easier to read than the mozilla one.

Comment: I followed your code. It doesn't work.
Sorry, I think I mixed up with something else in jQuery.
Before, I wrote button.click(alert("message"));
It executes no matter I click or not. Can you explain this? 
I thought eventhandler(function) is illegal anyway

Comment: Ok, to clarify, `focus(function())` will execute `function` immediately and pass whatever `function` returns to `focus` (which, presumably will set that as an eventhandler). In this case, our `makeHelpCallback` function, does itself return a function! alert does not return a function ;)

Comment: finally I achieved the result.
I think you forgot to pass the parameter at the execution () at the end which made the code not working. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

A simple example is much easier to follow:

```
var i;
var funcsToRun = [];
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  funcsToRun.push(function() { alert(i); });
}
funcsToRun[0](); // "3"
funcsToRun[1](); // "3"
funcsToRun[2](); // "3"
```

This is because the "i" used by the alert is part of a closure, and is stuck to the variable "i", which has a value of 3 by the time you execute your functions. But:

```
var i;
var funcsToRun = [];
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  funcsToRun.push(
    (function(idx) {
      return function() { alert(idx); };
    })(i)
  );
}
funcsToRun[0](); // "0"
funcsToRun[1](); // "1"
funcsToRun[2](); // "2"
```

This works because instead of attaching your alert to the variable "i", you're attaching it to "idx", which is evaluated immediately as the value of "i" inside of the loop, not after it. So the inner function is run immediately, but simply returns another function of `alert(0)` instead of `alert(i)`.

Using this line of thinking, you can apply this to a larger example.

Comment: Joe, Thank you for the very easy to understand example. 
I think I am missing something. What's the definition of a closure? Under what condition a function is said to be a closure? Is the closure a subset of anonymous function?

Comment: A closure is basically when you define a variable first, then create a function that uses that variable, but doesn't actually run it right away - that function can still use that variable, even if it's out of scope, but its value is what it is now, not what it was when the function was created. [Here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) is a great quick-read on the subject.

Comment: So, for the first code example you gave me, funcsToRun.push(function() { alert(i); }); is executed at the moment funcsToRun[0](); is called?

Comment: No prob. To answer your question, `funcsToRun[0]` is a function that will alert `i`'s value - it's the `function() { alert(i); }` part. When it's created, `i` has a value of zero, but that value is never used. When it's actually executed, `i` has a value of 3, so that's the alert that shows.

Comment: Best of luck with this stuff - closures in javascript can be tricky, so you really just have to do it a few times to get comfortable with the nested-function syntax, and it will start to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joe for the simplified example. I think I can get a grip of it.
I try to put Joe's example into procedure sequence. Let me know I am wrong.

```
var i;
var funcsToRun = [];

//for loop begins
i = 0
//i = 0
funcsToRun.push(function() { alert(i); }); // function(){ alert(i)} is not executed. i remains i.
i++ //i = 1
funcsToRun.push(function() { alert(i); });
i++ //i = 2
funcsToRun.push(function() { alert(i); });
i++ //i = 3 loop stopped. although the for loop completes, i remains in memory. It is not destroyed albeit its completion.

funcsToRun[0](); // function(){alert(i)} executes this moment, and i is 3 now.
funcsToRun[1](); // "3"
funcsToRun[2](); // "3"
```

Comment: i just realize that in javascript there is no local variable

say var i = 0; for(var i = 0; i++; i<5){} what's i's value now?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I achieved the result with jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="help">Helpful notes will appear here</p>
    <p>
        E-mail:
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    </p>
    <p>
        Name:
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        Age:
        <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
    </p>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        (function () {
            var helpText = [
            { 'id': 'email', 'help': 'Your e-mail address' },
            { 'id': 'name', 'help': 'Your full name' },
            { 'id': 'age', 'help': 'Your age (you must be over 16)' }
            ];

            for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
                var item = helpText[i];
                $("#" + item.id).focus(function (msg) {
                    return function () { $("#help").text(msg); }
                }(item.help));
            }
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you Joe and David